# Meaning of no up-front commitments about cloud computing

Tags: cloud, saas, paas, iaas

A book about cloud computing says, that cloud computing has those benefit:

```
• No up-front commitments
• On-demand access
• Nice pricing
• Simplified application acceleration and scalability
• Efficient resource allocation
• Energy efficiency
• Seamless creation and use of third-party services
```

what the "No up-front commitments" means in here?

Comment: Typically this means you don't have to contractually agree to a specific amount of usage up front. Many contracts have minimums and maximums built in, so even if you don't use a product much, you would still be obligated to a minimum payment...no up-fronts would avoid this scenario.

Comment: @MichaelGardner thank you! I think you give me a right answer. Could you make it as an answer? so, I can close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically this means you are not agreeing to contractual minimums in usage or billing up front.

Many contracts have minimum charges built in, so even if you don't use a product much, you would still be obligated to a minimum payment.  No up front commitments avoids this scenario.

Up front commitmants can still exist in cloud applications, where vendors provide discounted usage to encourage companies to sign longer term contracts.

Answer (score 1):

No up-front commitments

I think its like a electricity bill here in Pakistan people are obligated to pay minimum of 50 units every month.either they use 10 units or 50 they have to pay for 50 units.
in this case author is trying to say if you use 5 units of electricity you have to pay just for 5 units

**Reference **
**page 30 1.1.5 Characteristics and benefits, mastering of cloud computing Foundations and Applications
Programming by 
Rajkumar Buyya
S. Thamarai Selvi
Morgan Kaufmann**